# Clojure библиотека для миграции сущностей

Tags: миграция, clojure

Использую в проекте [migratus](https://github.com/yogthos/migratus) для миграции схемы БД при помощи SQL скриптов.
С некоторых пор понадобилось хранить сериализованные данные в некоторых полях базы. Хочется иметь возможность при необходимости обновлять их (полей с сериализованными данными) содержимое при миграции.

Подскажите, есть ли библиотека, поддерживающая наряду с SQL скриптами, еще и обычный clojure код?

Comment: Теоретически, в голову приходит решение через сам Migratus: Сделать [`modify-sql-fn`](https://github.com/yogthos/migratus#modify-sql-fn), который будет выполнять какой бы там ни было код, написанный в особом комментарии внутри SQL. Но возможно, стоит сделать фич-реквест. А ещё я слабо припоминаю, что видел какую-то библиотечку, где позволялось конструировать SQL по кусочкам с существенным применением произвольного Clojure. Если вспомню, я напишу.

Comment: Интересное использование modify-sql-fn =) Спасибо за идею.

Comment: Нашёл, то был [HugSQL](https://www.hugsql.org/). Но для натягивания его в миграции придётся брать что-то более обобщённое и базонезависимое, вроде [Ragtime](https://github.com/weavejester/ragtime). В общем, кроме решений уровня "напишите сами" ничего предложить, боюсь, не могу. Спросите в чатике Clojurians! Там могут знать.

Comment: В сторону ragtime я уже смотрел. А насчет HugSQL не понял, как вы предлагаете его использовать?

Comment: HugSQL позволяет использовать при составлении SQL произвольный Clojure, насколько я понял. У меня была мысль реализовать собственный формат миграций в чём-то, что реализует сам механизм миграций (определение того, какие применять и в каком порядке), но даёт реализовать конкретный их формат.

Comment: [`clj-sql-up`](https://github.com/ckuttruff/clj-sql-up) вроде вообще напрямую решает задачу :) Только уже давно не обновлялся.

Comment: Пожалуй clj-sql-up может подойти. Если я правильно понял идею, в сгенерированных файлах миграции можно выполнить произволный код в функциях up и down, которые должны возвращать пустые вектора, если не требуется выполнения SQL?

Comment: Ну, я это себе примерно так и представлял. В крайнем случае можно выполнить `["SELECT 1"]`, что c SQL означает примерно "сделай нифига".

Comment: Если к чему-то придёте, оставьте к своему вопросу ответ. А то даже мне интересно.